# Docker: how to work with local files?

Tags: file, docker, containers, local

Scenario is like this: I have a Docker image which is supposed to run on different machines. Let's assume the software within the image

1. reads a file,
2. calculates stuff based on that file and
3. writes an output file.

Now, the content of the input file changes from user to user, thus it must be easy to replace it. Also, the output file should be available to the user after the container has terminated.

The container runs fine when I inculde the input file into the image, but that's not convenient and not even close to what it should be like. I'm new to Docker and I did read the "Manage data in containers"-tutorial however I feel like it would be more elegant to not require too much docker-volume-creation-and-management from the user. The intended purpose is to spare installation time (aside from the docker installation) and make the deployment of the software as simple as possible.

Comment: Volume mounts are the way to go here.  If you want to make them easy to use, then write a script that wraps that all up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use -v to mount a host directory or file into the container. This will give you flexibility in deciding which input file to use as it resides on host without including it in the image.
e.g.

```
docker run -v <host dir>:/container_data_dir image cmd_to_run
```